# should SnapshotListeners be recalled each time that an app is restored from the background or returned to active

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've set up a Firestore SnapshotListener when my Swift app runs for the first time.  It's not clear whether the listener should be called each time the app is restored or made active though, to ensure that it is still running.  Can anyone advise on the best approach or what happens when the SnapshotListener is not called?

```
@objc func appReturnedToActive() {
    callSnapshotListener()
}
```

or

```
@objc func appReturnedFromBackground() {
    callSnapshotListener()
}
```

Comment: Is something not working the way you expect?  If that's case, please edit the question to explain the behavior that you're trying to avoid or fix.

Comment: The code in the question is not Firebase code so we don't know what your code does or how it's implemented. On the surface the question is understandable but to provide an accurate answer we need to know specifically what you're doing with Firebase. *I've set up a Firestore SnapshotListener* - what does 'set up' mean? What kind of SnapshotListener are you using? Please review the following [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Update the question and we'll take a look!

Comment: Hi Doug and Jay, it wasn't really a code (syntax) question.  To answer your question, "setup a Firestore SnapshotListener" means a call to *.addSnapshotListener{} in my backend interface.  I was wondering about the way to handle listeners and their behaviour when moving to the background or standby, but couldn't find anything about it in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Firestore documentation suggests, when you're no longer interested in listening to particular data then you should stop listening. If your app isn't configured to perform in the background, and you don't want it to, then you shouldn't be listening to data in the background. The most obvious reason for this is economy of engineering (we should always strive for maximum efficiency and if getting data updates in the background isn't necessary then it shouldn't be done). However, more practically, consider that an app is more likely to be killed by the OS if it's performing work in the background (versus an app that isn't) when other apps strain resources and that you're ultimately wasting money by paying for reads that will never be seen by anyone.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks.  It leaves me some architectural questions to fix as I refresh some lists of things to listen to when I initiate the listener.  I'll have to separate the lists from .addSnapshotListener{}.